# Difficulty updating Wordpress from 3.9.1 to 4.0

Tags: wordpress

When trying to automatically update Wordpress on [www.legalbeagles.info](http://legalbeagles.info) from 3.9.1 > 4.0 I receive the following error:

> An automated WordPress update has failed to complete - please attempt the update again now.

Not entirely confident in updating the files one by one manually, does anyone have suggestions of why this error may be appearing (novice so be gentle)?

And yes, I have read several others' questions but cannot see any similar issue answered in a way I may understand.

Comment: Usually, these kind of errors is related to the ability to overwrite files on the server. Have you checked permission? Additionally, [wordpress stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) may be a better option for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your file/folder permissions. Your webhost may have them set too strictly for WordPress to write its own temp folders and extract its own archive in `/wp-content/upgrade/`. See [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).
>
> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

Or, try a manual upgrade; all that involves is uploading a few folders and core files (and *not* overwriting wp-content and wp-config.php). See http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update